# Matlab plane fit - unable to get the root mean square error

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I need to find the RMS (root mean square) error of a plane fit to a set of 3D points. I'm using the [pcfitplane](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcfitplane.html) function, but I'm getting an array of indexes as result.

My code:

```
% Create the point cloud object
% XYZ is a N by 3 matrix containing the points
ptCloud = pointCloud(XYZ);
[~,rmse] = pcfitplane(ptCloud,maxDistance);

% rmse is a 1 by N array, and the values are also from 1 to N!
```

What I'm missing here? How can I get the RMS error correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not interpreting the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcfitplane.html) correctly. Here is how the prototypes are shown:

```
[model,inlierIndices,outlierIndices] = pcfitplane(ptCloudIn,maxDistance)
[___,rmse] = pcfitplane(ptCloudIn,maxDistance)
[___] = pcfitplane(ptCloudIn,maxDistance,Name,Value)
```

The long triple underscore means "all the output arguments from the sytaxes shown above", not "one argument". As you correctly noticed, you are getting the `inlierIndices` back. You are trying to do something like this:

```
[~,~,~,rmse] = pcfitplane(ptCloud,maxDistance);
```

The three tildes are the long underscore. They represent `model,inlierIndices,outlierIndices`. Hope that helps you with future docs as well.

Comment: Oh! That is what I was missing! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah. It's nice that you very clearly read and understood the docs before posting. It happens surprisingly rarely.